# Unity3D TextMeshPro in UWP

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp

I stuck on deploying an Unity3D game as UWP, which uses TextMeshPro:

```
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: TextMeshPro-1.0.55.56.0b12, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'TextMeshPro-1.0.55.56.0b12.dll'
```

The solution explorer in Visual Studio (2017 Community) shows no exclamation mark in the referenced assemblies. Does anyone else experienced this or knows a solution (maybe not to not-using textmeshpro)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I used Unity3d 5.6.xxx I tried to upgrade to Unity3d 2017.1 which solves the problem ... At least: The error do not appear anymore